# How to take a column from a txt file and save in a new matrix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I did this code to go through a folder, find all .txt files and take the 4th column from this .txt file (has a lot of columns)  and put in a new numpy array (data)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import mu_0
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


data=np.zeros((44,14)) # there are 14 .txt files and the 4th column has 44 lines
indx = 0
import os
Path = "my path"
filelist = os.listdir(Path)
for i in filelist:
    if i.endswith(".txt"): 

        newpath = Path+ '/'+i 
        print(newpath) # check if the path and file is right
        dados= pd.read_table(newpath,header=None)
        data[:,indx] = dados[:][4]
        indx = indx+1
```

the error I'm getting is:
First: I have some problem with index, because is starting at 1 and should be at 0. 
Second: Is just taking the 4th column from the first .txt file and putting in the array data, but then stops and do not run through the other files.

This is the errror: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 49, saw 7

Comment: If you want the 4th column from `dados`, then don't you want the 3rd index of the df? Also I'd try to index the df with `iloc` or `loc` for integer and label based indexing respectively, just so that you know for sure the API calls are definitely not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import os
import pandas as pd

workingpath = os.getcwd()
files = []

for file in os.listdir(workingpath):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        files.append(os.path.join(workingpath,file))

data = pd.DataFrame()
for col, file in enumerate(files):
    dados = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    data[col] = dados.iloc[:,4]

data = data.to_numpy()
```

Comment: I have tried this and is not working, I got this error : IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: just appdated,  data should have been a DataFrame and not a list